# How can I fix Hubsite Navigation while scrolling in sharepoint online using Modern page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, hub-site

I want to fix the hubsite navigation in sharepoint online modern look while scrolling. Both the navigations (Hubsite and Site) should be visible even if you scroll down at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test in SharePoint online, I encounter the same behavior with hub navigation.

This is the new feature named "[Shy header](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=Shy%2Cheader)" for collapsing the menu when scrolling hides the hub navigation.

[image]

You can vote for the following uservoice to report your request:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/41180146-option-to-make-hub-navigation-sticky